# AML Notebook VM auto shutdown policy

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Whether an auto shutdown policy can be set to turn off Notebook VM?.Is this need to shutdown the VM Notebook by the user?

Comment: Is there any news on that for Azure ML compute instances?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime....a team of MSFT architects developed the following Azure Samples solution to fill this gap:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMLResourceGovernance

It uses Logic Apps to orchestrate Container Instances to perform Azure ML resource governance related tasks (such as scheduled shutdowns).

Answer (score 1):

Auto-shutdown is currently not enabled for Compute Instances or Notebook VM but it is on our road map. Details will be provided in [Azure Updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=ai-machine-learning) when this feature is in preview, in development, or becomes available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Auto shutdown is on roadmap, Workaround While you can see and change settings for the underlying IaaS VM,if using Azure VM Auto-shutdown (also Automation Runbook) is to start the VM from the Azure VM resource blade first, then restart in the Azure ML Workspace UI.

Azure Notebooks starts the underlying virtual machine whenever you run a notebook or other file. The server automatically saves files and shuts down after 60 minutes of inactivity. You can also stop the server at any time with the Shutdown command (keyboard shortcut: h). Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notebooks/configure-manage-azure-notebooks-projects.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Machine Learning Compute Instance Auto shutdown is now in private preview - contact your local Microsoft representative to have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a new Auto-Shutdown preview feature for the compute instance in Azure Machine Learning Service. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#configure-auto-stop-preview)
Make sure to enable this preview feature as in below image.
[image]

Then check the compute instance/schedules option to see the new feature as below.
[image]

Note also we can control the auto-shutdown time on a subscription level using a built-in policy. details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#azure-policy-support)